# Why am I getting a GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, framebuffer

I'm developing an Android 2.2 app with NDK r6b. I'm developing OpenGL ES 2.0 code as native code (C++).

I have this C++ code:

```
RenderingEngine2::RenderingEngine2()
{
    // Create & bind the color buffer so that the caller can allocate its space.
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_renderbuffer);
    checkGlError("01 - glGenRenderbuffers");
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_renderbuffer);
    checkGlError("02 - glBindRenderbuffer");
    LOG("RenderingEngine2::RenderingEngine2()");
}

void RenderingEngine2::Initialize(int width, int height)
{
    LOG("RenderingEngine2::Initialize");
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, width, height);
    // Create the framebuffer object and attach the color buffer.

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_framebuffer);
    checkGlError("03 - glGenFramebuffers");
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebuffer);
    checkGlError("04 - glBindFramebuffer");
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                              GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                              GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                              m_renderbuffer);
    checkGlError("05 - glFramebufferRenderbuffer");

    GLint status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        LOG("Framebuffer completed");
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("Framebuffer error: (0x%x)", status);
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    checkGlError("06 - glViewPort");

    m_simpleProgram = BuildProgram(SimpleVertexShader, SimpleFragmentShader);

    glUseProgram(m_simpleProgram);
    checkGlError("07 - glUseProgram");

    // Initialize the projection matrix.
    ApplyOrtho(2, 3);

    // Initialize rotation animation state.
    OnRotate(DeviceOrientationPortrait);
    m_currentAngle = m_desiredAngle;
}
```

When I run it, I get a GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create depth and stencil renderbuffers:

```
// depth
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_depthRenderbuffer);
checkGlError("01 - glGenRenderbuffers");
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthRenderbuffer);
checkGlError("02 - glBindRenderbuffer");
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);

// stencil
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_stencilRenderbuffer);
checkGlError("01 - glGenRenderbuffers");
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_stencilRenderbuffer);
checkGlError("02 - glBindRenderbuffer");
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
```

and then attach them to the framebuffer:

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthRenderbuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_stencilRenderbuffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allocate your render buffer with glRenderbufferStorage().

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the problem. I've uncommented it, and I still getting the same error. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A **possible** solution is to use the default window-system-provided framebuffer, which is 0.

**I don't like this solution** because I don't know why I can't generate a FrameBuffer or if I can use the default window-system-provided framebuffer.

Here is my **modified** code:

```
RenderingEngine2::RenderingEngine2()
{
    // Create & bind the color buffer so that the caller can allocate its space.
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_renderbuffer);
    checkGlError("01 - glGenRenderbuffers");
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_renderbuffer);
    checkGlError("02 - glBindRenderbuffer");
    LOG("RenderingEngine2::RenderingEngine2()");
}

void RenderingEngine2::Initialize(int width, int height)
{
    LOG("RenderingEngine2::Initialize");
/*
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, width, height);
    // Create the framebuffer object and attach the color buffer.

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_framebuffer);
    */
    m_framebuffer = (GLuint) 0;
    checkGlError("03 - glGenFramebuffers");
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebuffer);
    checkGlError("04 - glBindFramebuffer");

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                              GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                              GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                              m_renderbuffer);
    checkGlError("05 - glFramebufferRenderbuffer");

    GLint status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        LOG("Framebuffer completed");
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("Framebuffer error: (0x%x)", status);
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    checkGlError("06 - glViewPort");

    m_simpleProgram = BuildProgram(SimpleVertexShader, SimpleFragmentShader);

    glUseProgram(m_simpleProgram);
    checkGlError("07 - glUseProgram");

    // Initialize the projection matrix.
    ApplyOrtho(2, 3);

    // Initialize rotation animation state.
    OnRotate(DeviceOrientationPortrait);
    m_currentAngle = m_desiredAngle;
}
```